# How to change the color of one Details Label in power bi Donut chart

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, visualization

See this image for reference:

[image]

I am trying to show the Unmatched set's details label['**12316 (31.4%)**'] in RED Color instead of black color(highlighted in yellow in the attached pic for ref).

Note - I have checked Format under visualizations and when I change the color in details label, both sets are changing.

How to do that without affecting Matched set['**26901 (68.6%)**'] in the same donut chart.

*Attached the working area pic for ref.*

[image]

Comment: I think there is no option for this at present in powerbi. i checked one of the feedback - https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/40505656-conditional-formatting-donut-charts . if any want this, upvote it.

Comment: Glad you got your solution, pls provide your own answer and accept it

Comment: Thanks @Jayendran! Yup, provided the same as answer. Thanks for helping me to redirect this to official powerbi community too as idea/feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searched in many places and discussed with persons who worked a lot in power bi stuffs. At this point of time, there is no option to edit particular details label alone in Donut Chart.

This is **at idea/feedback level alone**. May be , hopes Power Bi will implement this in nearby future.

If you also want this in power bi, let the power bi community to know this things and give your votes at power bi site's feedback - https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/40505656-conditional-formatting-donut-charts